# Thread stopped...access violation at 0x6: read of address 0x6

Tags: c

I am getting an error saying: Thread stopped.....access violation at 0x6:read of address 0x6.
However my code doesn't have such address.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    void main ()
    {
     int i,j,A[4][5],c=0;
     for(j=0;j<5;j++)
      for(i=0;j<4;i++)
       {
        A[i][j]=c;
        c++;
       }
     for(i=0;i<4;i++)
      {
       for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        printf("%d\t",A[i][j]);
       printf("\n");
      }
     getch();
    }
```

I was asked to enter a double array column by column instead of row by row, and I want to verify my method so I tried to print it out but had no luck doing so.

Comment: Using a debugger to step through this code should show you the error immediately. Heck, even getting a backtrace would show you what's up in short order.

Comment: hmm. you should be careful when using copy-paste :D

Answer (score 10):

```
  for(i=0;j<4;i++)
          ^^
```

Shouldn't this be:

```
  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
```

`j<4` is always true once it enters inner the loop for the first time and is the reason for memory access violation.

Comment: Oh thanks, I made this program by altering a previous one, and it seems that I missed changing ALL what I should have changed, thanks:D